# Does signature of custom assignment operator=() matter when I just want to disable it?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I need to disable the copy assignment operator. This will work:

```
A& operator=(const A&);
```

Will it work if I don't specify exact parameters for `operator=`?
I mean something like this:

```
void operator=(void);
```

The returning value is right, I can write whatever I want, but what about the parameter type?
Will this override the default `operator=` for class?

Comment: "will it work..."; Did you *try* ?

Comment: assignment must take exactly one argument.

Comment: @WhozCraig, yes I can try and see it works or not, but I want to know why.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From [12.8p17](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy#17) of the C++ standard draft:

> A user-declared copy assignment operator `X::operator=` is a non-static non-template member function of class `X` with exactly one parameter of type `X`, `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`.

I guess this replies better than any other test or sample code.

Note that something similar applies also to the move assignment operator, see [12.8p19](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy#19):

> A user-declared move assignment operator X::operator= is a non-static non-template member function of class X with exactly one parameter of type X&&, const X&&, volatile X&&, or const volatile X&&.

These also confirm that, as you guessed, return value types don't matter.

Answer (score 9):

There can be different kinds of assignments. Only *copy assignment* and *move assignment* are potentially generated by the compiler. They are generated if there is no copy/move assignment. So, if you want to disable copy and/or move assignment the argument type does matter although there is some flexibility as copy assignment can different argument types. The return type doesn't matter, though.

```
class A {
public:
    void operator=() = delete; // not legal: assignment takes exactly one argument
    void operator=(A) = delete; // OK: copy assignment disabled
    void operator=(A&) = delete; // OK: copy assignment disabled
    void operator=(A const&) = delete; // OK: copy assignment disabled
    void operator=(A&&) = delete; // OK: move assignment disabled
};
```

There are also variations replacing `const` by `volatile` or `const volatile` qualifying as copy/move assignments. When you disable a copy assignment, automatic generation of move assignment will be disabled, too. If you disable move assignment, I think copy assignment would still be generated. If you disable anything which cannot be a copy or move assignment, copy/move assignment are still generated.

Answer (score 6):

This is exact definition of an user-declared copy assignment operator from [current standard](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf) (§ 12.8 p. 17):

> A user-declared copy assignment operator `X::operator=` is a non-static
>   non-template member function of `class X` with exactly one parameter of
>   type `X, X&, const X&, volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`.

Notes:

- An overloaded assignment operator must be declared to have only one
  parameter; see 13.5.3.
- More than one form of copy assignment operator may be declared for a class.
- If a class X only has a copy assignment operator with a parameter of type X&, an expression of type const X cannot be assigned to an object of type X.

Example:

```
struct X {
X();
X& operator=(X&);
};
const X cx;
X x;
void f() {
x = cx; // error: X::operator=(X&) cannot assign cx into x
}
```

Also, please, use **delete** from C++11 standard.

You can now set functions as Defaulted or Deleted.

You can now write directly that you would like to disable copying.

```
class A {
A(const A&) = delete;
A& operator=(const A&) = delete;    // Disallow copying
};
```

You can also explicitly inform compiler that you want default copy of a class. This way you can provide custom default constructor and still get default versions of other compiler-generated methods from compiler.

```
class B {
    B(const Y&) = default;
    B& operator=(const B&) = default;   // default copy 
};
```